# Angular Check Box with limit and one can select un select anything

Tags: angularjs

> I need to create multi level angular checkbox based on user input
>
> ```
> Maximum Parent Checkbox 3
> One can select and unselect.
> On unchecking the checkbox should be removed from the view.
> If there is only one left it can't be removed though unchecked and making all list checkbox disabled.
> Each parent Checkbox carries list of checkbox inside if that list is selected then only add option is available to add new checkbox.
> ```

```
CheckBox -1 
List A
LISt B
List C
List D

CheckBox -2
List A
LISt B
List C
List D

CheckBox -3
List A
LISt B
List C
List D
```

> If From check box 1 list any option is selected then add new checkbox
>   option should appear and same goes with other and on un-selection that
>   block should be removed and only maximum 3 checkbox can be created.

http://jsfiddle.net/L2je0L9v/